# Cant go back from post_one page to index.html

Tags: html

I have single portfolio page called index.html with different pages for blog post, like post_one, post_two etc. My whole index.html page includes sections like work, about, services, contact and it is on single index.html page. I am moving through sections by id's which are on every main container of specified section.

```
<li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

The problem is that i want for blog post to be on separated pages like post_one.html and when i do that i can go back to index.html from that post_one page, this is the navigation on post_one.html page from which i have to go back to index.html

```
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Comment: lack of info is hard to troubleshoot what you actually hit, the location of your 2 file also important as it might be the reason why one is working fine but no the other

Comment: The way you tell us your problem, it seems like this should work. Could you show us your file hierarchy? Maybe a bit more code / a reproducible snippet(s)?

Comment: In my navigation I can move through sections on index.html page with id's

Comment: Yes..... Go on? We can't magically know what you mean, man. Try to explain as good as possible. That way it won't take long.

Comment: Find the solution, js plugin was preventing default behavior on a page because it was single page template, sorry for lack of information, I was under big pressure on geting the job done, anyway it is all fixed by removing preventDefault method